# Setting my Teams presence status from PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-teams

As posted [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_pres/setting-my-teams-presence-status-from-powershell/4a432257-b4c8-4161-b5d2-71f834c3c252) I’m looking for a way to set the current user’s presence in Teams like I do for Skype for Business using the Lync SDK.

Is there a similar SDK for Teams, sporting a similar API?

I have the feeling past answers here are conflicting and/or obsolete and/or not applicable to the situation where our org currently has Skype for Business and Teams running side by side, and **presence in each is independent**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no any PowerShell command available to change Teams presence status. But, any new PowerShell command is published will automatically update in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/?view=teams-ps). So, you may keep monitor this above mentioned article for Teams PowerShell command updates.

On the other hand, at present we need to change Teams presence status manually by clicking Teams profile picture symbol > click on the status which we want to set.

Comment: You can now set Teams presence using API see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell

My problem however has been identifying my Teams Application ID for use in that call. Any ideas?